# How do I create a Field<T> from a value T in jOOQ, explicitly?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

In jOOQ, it is easy to use bind variables in expressions like:

```java
MY_TABLE.COL.eq(1);
MY_TABLE.COL.in(1, 2, 3);
MY_TABLE.COL.between(1).and(10);
```

All of the above methods accept both `T` and `Field<T>` types, e.g. [`Field.eq(T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#eq(T)) or [`Field.eq(Field<T>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#eq(org.jooq.Field)). But what if I want to put the bind variable on the left side of the expression? These obviously don't work:

```java
1.eq(MY_TABLE.COL);
1.in(MY_TABLE.COL1, MY_TABLE.COL2, MY_TABLE.COL3);
1.between(MY_TABLE.COL1).and(MY_TABLE.COL2);
```

How can I turn those `1` or `"xyz"` into `Field<Integer>` or `Field<String>`, etc.?

(This is such a popular question on the jOOQ mailing list, etc., so I'm documenting it here)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The methods accepting `T` are just convenience methods. Behind the scenes, they all wrap the `T` argument in [`DSL.val(T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val(T))

```java
// This
MY_TABLE.COL.eq(1);

// Is just convenience for this:
MY_TABLE.COL.eq(val(1));

// Or rather, this one to be precise
MY_TABLE.COL.eq(val(1, MY_TABLE.COL.getDataType()));
```

Because wrapping everything in `val()` would be very verbose and cumbersome, all of jOOQ's API accepting `Field<T>` also accepts `T` for convenience. If Java had untagged union types, the parameter types of such methods would be `T|Field<T>`.

In rare cases, users need to explicitly wrap their bind values in `val()`, including:

- When the bind value is on the left hand side of an expression
- When the bind value is used in a clause that doesn't support such overloads, e.g. in `select()`
- When functions with many overloads require a `Field<T>` type for one of the parameters

So, just write:

```java
val(1).eq(MY_TABLE.COL);
val(1).in(MY_TABLE.COL1, MY_TABLE.COL2, MY_TABLE.COL3);
val(1).between(MY_TABLE.COL1).and(MY_TABLE.COL2);
```

Note there's also [`DSL.inline(T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline(T)) to create "inline values", or also "constants", "literals", instead of bind values.

See also:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/indexed-parameters/
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/