# Specify function as value in Jooq

Tags: jooq

Using Jooq, I would like to specify the value of a field during insert as a function.

In SQL Server the equivalent query is:

`insert into table (a, t) values ('foo', SYSDATETIME())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mixing bind values with expressions:

Assuming you're using [generated code](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/), write this:

```java
// Assuming this static import, as always:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

ctx.insertInto(TABLE)
   .columns(TABLE.A, TABLE.T)
   .values(val("foo"), currentTimestamp()) // or currentLocalDateTime()
   .execute();
```

The `VALUES()` clause only has 2 overloads:

- Accepting only bind variables
- Accepting only expressions

It doesn't have an overload mixing both things, because there would be an exponential number of needed overloads. So the key thing to do here is to wrap your [bind variables](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/indexed-parameters/) using [`DSL.val()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val(T)) explicitly.

See also this question:
[How do I create a Field<T> from a value T in jOOQ, explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67522537/521799)

#### A note on `SYSDATETIME`

jOOQ supports the standard SQL `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` expression via [`DSL.currentTimestamp()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#currentTimestamp()) and [`DSL.currentLocalDateTime()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#currentLocalDateTime()). If you prefer using `SYSDATETIME`, you can create a [plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) for that, or use [`DSL.function()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#function(org.jooq.Name,org.jooq.DataType,org.jooq.Field...))

Comment: thanks Lukas, all my searching related to "functions" and "currentTimestamp" gave me examples of SELECTs that used DSL.field(). Just my perspective, but an example of using val() in the INSERT documentation might be useful. That was the missing link for me.

Comment: @root: we could add an example of val() in every single section... Anyway. People will now find this Q&A