# converting string to number inside Jooq select - Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jooq, jooq-sbt-plugin, jooq-codegen

I am using jooq's DSL.select in my Java code, I have scenario where I need to determine the index from a string.
Used `DSL.substring("hello123",6,1)` to get the desired index value as string, but no method supporting in DSL to convert it to a number.
Example:

```java
DSL.select(
       COL1, 
       COL2, 
       COL3,
       DSL.substring("Test123456"), 
       1, 
       DSL.substring("hello123",6,1))
   .from(TABLE)
```

the nested substring need to be converted into number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Converting strings to numbers

Use the [`CAST` expression](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/cast-expressions/):

```java
// Both are equivalent
cast(substring("hello123", 6), SQLDataType.NUMERIC);
substring("hello123", 6).cast(SQLDataType.NUMERIC);
```

As always, this is assuming the following static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

#### Mixing `Field<?>` expressions with bind values

You've mixed your `Field<?>` expression with a bind value `1` in your `SELECT` clause. There's no such convenience overload for `SELECT` (there would be too many permutations), so you'll have to [wrap the bind value explicitly using](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/indexed-parameters/):

```java
val(1)
```

See also: [How do I create a Field<T> from a value T in jOOQ, explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67522537/521799)

Comment: when we use either DSL.substring("hello123",6,2).cast(Integer.class) or DSL.substring("hello123",6,2).cast(SQLDataType. NUMERIC) both are yielding to Field<?> type  and from Field<> to Integer we don't have any handy methods

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A `Field<T>` is an expression (in SQL) of type `T`. You can only get a `T` reference by executing the query and projecting the `Field<T>` expression. Is that what your question is about?

Answer (score 0):

substring(Field<String >, int, int) has an overloaded method
substring(Field<String>, Field<? Extends Integer>, Field<? Extends Integer>)

of course the first method internally calling the second one.

```
DSL.select(
       COL1, 
       COL2, 
       COL3,
       DSL.substring("Test123456"), 
                    DSL.cast("1", SQLDataType.INTEGER),     
                    DSL.substring("hello123",6,1).cast(SQLDataType.INTEGER))
   .from(TABLE)
```