# JOOQ sequences in insertinto, set vs values

Tags: java, jooq

I have a simple table with a seqence.
When I use sequence.nextval() in the insertInto .set method everything is fine.
When I use sequence.nextval() in the insertInto .values method with just the sequence, specifiend again everything is fine.
When I use sequence.nextval() in the insertInto .values method with more than the sequence, specifiend, I get an error.

This is OK

```
        int w = dslContext
                .insertInto(APPOINTMENTTYPE)
                .set(APPOINTMENTTYPE.MC, 501559436L)
                .set(APPOINTMENTTYPE.ID, HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval())
                .set(APPOINTMENTTYPE.NAME, "test name")
                .set(APPOINTMENTTYPE.DESCRIPTION, "test description")
                .set(APPOINTMENTTYPE.BLUE, 255)
                .set(APPOINTMENTTYPE.GREEN, 255)
                .set(APPOINTMENTTYPE.RED, 255)
                .set(APPOINTMENTTYPE.REMINDERINTERVAL, 1)
                .execute();
```

This is also OK

```
        int x = dslContext.insertInto(APPOINTMENTTYPE, 
APPOINTMENTTYPE.ID).values(APPOINTMENTTYPE_SEQ.nextval()).execute();
```

This gives the error `Cannot resolve method 'values(Field<Long>, int)'`

```
        int y = dslContext.insertInto(APPOINTMENTTYPE, APPOINTMENTTYPE.ID, APPOINTMENTTYPE.BLUE).values(APPOINTMENTTYPE_SEQ.nextval(), 255).execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two sets of overloads of the `values()` clause:

- One where all arguments are bind values, i.e. `values(T1, T2, ...)`
- One where all arguments are expressions, i.e. `values(Field<T1>, Field<T2>, ...)`

If arbitrary combinations of bind values and expressions were to be supported, we'd quickly get a prohibitive (exponential!) number of combinations in an already big API.

As such, in your case, you just have to wrap your bind value using `DSL.val()` explicitly, i.e. `DSL.val(255)`. I.e. like this:

```java
int x = dslContext
    .insertInto(APPOINTMENTTYPE, APPOINTMENTTYPE.ID, APPOINTMENTTYPE.BLUE)
    .values(APPOINTMENTTYPE_SEQ.nextval(), DSL.val(255))
    .execute();
```

See also:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/indexed-parameters/
- [How do I create a Field<T> from a value T in jOOQ, explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67522537/521799)

This limitation obviously doesn't affect methods with fixed sets of arguments, such as `set()`

Comment: Lukas, thanks for the prompt reply, I am absolutely brand new to JOOQ so would really appreciate the correct syntax for the failing values example above. Working my way through tutorials and the pdf.

Comment: @ChiralSystems: *you just have to wrap your bind value using DSL.val() explicitly* really just means wrap `256` using `DSL.val()`

Comment: I tried this `int x = dslContext.insertInto(APPOINTMENTTYPE, APPOINTMENTTYPE.ID, APPOINTMENTTYPE.BLUE).values(DSL.val(APPOINTMENTTYPE_SEQ.nextval()), 255).execute();`  but get the error `Cannot resolve method 'values(Param<T>, int)'`

Comment: OK, now wrap `255` using `DSL.val()`, as in `DSL.val(255)`. I don't know how else I can phrase this :) You can also click on the links I provided, and read those pages...

Comment: I tried that already based on your comment about having bind value combinations. so `int x = dslContext.insertInto(APPOINTMENTTYPE, APPOINTMENTTYPE.ID, APPOINTMENTTYPE.BLUE).values(DSL.val(APPOINTMENTTYPE_SEQ.nextval()), DSL.val(255)).execute();` but get the error `Cannot resolve method 'values(Param<T>, Param<Integer>)'`. I am using jooq 3.18.7 in a spring boot 3.1.5 project

Comment: `APPOINTMENTTYPE_SEQ.nextval()`  is an expression of type `Field<T>`. It is already of the correct type for the `values(Field<T1>, Field<T2>)` overload. Why did you try to wrap it? Only bind values need to be wrapped to pass them to that overload.

Comment: Anyway, I just added the correct answer. I don't know how else to explain this. Perhaps it "clicks" once you see it?