Jooq using coalesce in numerical expressions
How do you use coalese with Jooq in numerical expressions?
For example, I want something like .where(TEST_TABLE.NUMBER).eq(5.minus(DSL.coalesce(TEST_TABLE.OTHERNUMBER, 0)))
but minus is expecting an argument of type number (like int double etc.) as an argument and I get "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."
If I just have .eq(DSL.coalesce(TEST_TABLE.OTHERNUMBER, 0)) then it works fine. Also, just running it as a Postgres query like WHERE test_table.number = (5 - COALESCE(test_table.othernumber)) works fine. Any suggestions?
I tried adding .cast(SQLDataType.NUMERIC) but get the same issue.

The question doesn't really have anything to do with using the arithmetic expression in COALESCE(). It's just a matter of how to explicitly wrap the bind value 5 of type Integer in a Field<Integer> representing that bind value, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/67522537/521799
